# CoreLocation region delegates not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, gps, core-location

I am building an application specifically a location based app, so I need to get the user coordinates the longitude and the latitude and its worked.

Now I need to know if the user enter some region that I predefined using the `CLLocationManager` delegates, so I override the `didEnterRegion` with an `NSLog` statement to know if the user enter the region.

In

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

I call the `startMonitoringForRegion:` but nothing happen in delegates like `didEnterRegion` or `monitoringDidFailForRegion` or any delegates for the `CLRegion`.

Here is some of my code :

```
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
   {
        locLongittude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        locLattiude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;

        self.regionTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(monitorRegion) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
   }

   -(void)startMonitor:(float)latitude longitude:(float)longitude radius:(float)radius
   {
      CLLocationCoordinate2D home;
      home.latitude = latitude;
      home.longitude = longitude;

      CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:home radius:radius identifier:@"home"];

      if([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled] && [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable])
          [locManager startMonitoringForRegion:region desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest]; 

      NSLog(@"Count: %d region aval %d enable %d",[[locManager monitoredRegions]count], [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable],[CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled]);
      for( CLRegion* region in locManager.monitoredRegions )
      NSLog( @"%@", region );
   }

   -(void)monitorRegion
   {
      [self startMonitor:31.971160 longitude:35.832465 radius:10000.0];
   }
```

Edit : all the testing done using the simulator and simulate the location using Product-> Debug -> Simulate Location

Ok guys it works. The code above works great the problem was that is to make the `didEnterRegion` method get called is to be outside the region you need to enter then you enter it to make it work.

What I was doing is in the simulation I always choose a coordinate inside the region I need to enter and that was the problem it must be outside the region.

So here is my code to share with you

Update : I am wondering why the didExitRegion doesn't get called when I leave the region?

Comment: Can you print out the regions so you know they are added to the monitor stack?

Comment: yes its added (for now I have just one region)
2012-06-05 12:30:15.929 GPS_Location[1415:f803](identifier home) <+31.97116089,+35.83246613> radius 10000.00m

Answer (score 0):

As per my own experience, it looks like Region Monitoring depends on Cell Change events (why Apple designed it this way? I guess to increase the battery life). So, this implementation is not ideal.

Ideally it should work whenever you cross the boundary, but it doesn't happens the same way on iPhone. Even with the builtin Reminder app, sometimes it fails for nearby by location-based reminders.

So in your case I think the cell change event doesn't occur and that why didExitRegion is not called. You can double check it by using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.